# Bias tee in Vector Network Analyzer

Tags: bias, mixer, vna

Can I use a bias tee in the back of a VNA (E5080B) as a port 1 and 2, or do I need a mixer for it? I want to measure the network parameters of a device that requires bias.

Comment: A bias tee for what purpose? To measure the network parameters of a device that requires bias? Please [edit] your question with the relevant details.

Comment: @nanofarad yes I want to measure the network parameters of a device that requires bias.

Comment: Then yes, you need a bias tee (and may want to correct for its own network parameters as part of calibration or data analysis). A mixer doesn't sound like the right device to use here.

Answer (score 1):

You connect the bias T between one port of the VNA and the device.

If you calibrate at the VNA ports, then you're measuring the 'bias T + device', which may or may not be what you want.

If you calibrate at the bias T and the other port, then you're measuring the device alone.